# ConcurrentModificationException java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I can be the implementation of a chat app to show users chat only the can get user_id to be sent or receive a message to store in user-list and select the user to be added in the list some  error like a User list if added user 1 and add user 2 when and user 1 again the exception in ArrayList [image]

```
 for (String id : usersList)
                    if (equal(user.getId(), id)) {
                        if (mUseres.size() != 0) {
                            for (User user1 : mUseres) {
                                if (!equal(user.getId(), user1.getId())) {
                                    mUseres.add(user);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            mUseres.add(user);
                        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
   for (User user1 : mUseres) {
       if (!equal(user.getId(), user1.getId())) {
       mUseres.add(user);
    }
```

You are iterating `mUseres` (`for`....) and **at same time** you are adding new items (`mUseres.add`)

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify the List while iterating through it.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception